# UISplitViewController with multiple detail ViewControllers in tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I am trying to implement a UISplitViewController on tvOSapp which has a Master ViewController with a UITableView displaying a menu. I also have an Initial Detail ViewController assigned.

What I want to achieve is that when a row in the Master ViewController menu is clicked, the initial detailViewController should be replaced by another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `showDetailViewController(vc: UIViewController, sender: Any?)` is for.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Where to implement this func in app delegate or in root View controller(tableView) ?

Comment: "when a row in the Master ViewController menu is clicked" sounds like you should call this in your `tableView(_:,didSelectRowAt:)` method

Comment: Do you have some experience with video player for tvOS? I now how to implement video but I would like to have related videos on the bottom,like animation when I swipe down to get related videos for this category ?